# java String replace characters

Tags: java, string, replace, split

I need your help for one tricky problem.
I have one **map** like below

```
Map<Integer, String> ruleMap = new HashMap<>();
ruleMap.put(1, "A");
ruleMap.put(12, "Test - 12");
ruleMap.put(1012, "Test Metadata 12 A");
```

and I have one **rule** in which I am separating ids and collecting them into a list. By iterating over the list, I am replacing its ids by its respective value from map.

code :

```
String rule = "1 AND 12 OR 1012 AND 12 or 1012";

List < String > idList = new ArrayList < > ();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(rule);
while (m.find()) {
    idList.add(m.group());
}
for (String id: idList) {
    if (ObjectUtils.isNonEmpty(ruleMap.get(Integer.parseInt(id)))) {
        rule = rule.replaceFirst(id, ruleMap.get(Integer.parseInt(id)));
    }
}
System.out.println(rule);
```

I am getting output like this -

```
A AND Test - Test - 12 OR Test Metadata 12 A AND 12 or Test Metadata 12 A
```

as you can see for the first iteration of `id 12` replaced its respected value but on the second occurrence of the `id 1`2 replaced the value `Test - 12` to `Test - Test - 12`.

So can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be doing regex replacement with proper word boundaries.  I suggest using a regex iterator (as you were already doing), but use the pattern `\b\d+\b` to match only full number strings.  Then, at each match, do a lookup in the rule map, if the number be present, to find a replacement value.  Use `Matcher#appendReplacement` to build out the replacement string as you go along.

```
Map<String, String> ruleMap = new HashMap<>();
ruleMap.put("1", "A");
ruleMap.put("12", "Test - 12");
ruleMap.put("1012", "Test Metadata 12 A");

String rule = "1 AND 12 OR 1012 AND 12 or 1012";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(rule);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  
while(m.find()) {
    if (ruleMap.containsKey(m.group(0))) {
        m.appendReplacement(buffer, ruleMap.get(m.group(0)));
    }
}

m.appendTail(buffer);

System.out.println(rule + "\n" + buffer.toString());
```

This prints:

```
1 AND 12 OR 1012 AND 12 or 1012
A AND Test - 12 OR Test Metadata 12 A AND Test - 12 or Test Metadata 12 A
```

Comment: You need to at least give me some context here if you want debugging help.

Comment: I think my rule map contains any special characters like $ or #% or ( )  which causing this error.

Comment: I know how to fix this, but you're really asking a different question now.

Comment: sorry, Tim but can you tell me what causes this kind of error. like I have checked but I don't have any special characters in my rule map. so is there any other possibilities which causing this error?

Comment: You need to regex escape the search terms using [Pattern#quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)).  But again, the question you actually asked above searches for only numbers.  I suggest opening a new question if you can't resolve it on your own.

Comment: I just want to allow special characters like $ # @  for the above example.
Do I need to change my Regex for that?

Comment: I have updated my code as following :: And It worked.. Thank you buddy you helped me a lot. 
match.appendReplacement(buffer,
      Matcher.quoteReplacement(ruleMap.get(match.group(0))));

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Java 9 or higher you could also use [`Matcher#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)):

```java
Map<Integer, String> ruleMap = new HashMap<>();
ruleMap.put(1, "A");
ruleMap.put(12, "Test - 12");
ruleMap.put(1012, "Test Metadata 12 A");

String rule = "1 AND 12 OR 1012 AND 12 or 1012";

rule = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b")
        .matcher(rule)
        .replaceAll(m -> ruleMap.getOrDefault(
                Integer.parseInt(m.group()), m.group()));

System.out.println(rule);
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for pointing that out. I'll add `Map.getOrDefault` to address that issue.